# Create Dynamic SQL Server with password in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, passwords

How can I create a SQL Server `.mdf` database file in some folder with a help of C#? Also need to do to access the database it was only the application. How can I do it?

Comment: SQL Server is a **server-based** solution - it's not primarily designed to handle "free-floating" `.mdf` files, and its security system is a bit more advanced than protecting an `.mdf` file with a password ..... either you need the power of SQL Server - on the **server** - then you need to learn about how SQL Server handles databases and their security - or then you need something a lot less sophisticated than an `.mdf` file

Comment: Try telling us what you have tried so far and the issues you have had or found in your research as your question at the moment doesn't demonstrate any effort on your part to solve the issue. We might be in a much better position to help then.